# Display div element if specific value exists in JSON object in JavaScript Vue Js

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, vuetify.js

I need to display Div element if specific value exists on JSON object and I have tried using array I could success but I don't know how to do in JSON object. Simply I need to display div if value called "Channel" exists on JSON object.

Below code that I tried but it didn't work

```
activationTypes: [
{
"activationTypeId": 1,
"name": "SMS"
},
{
"activationTypeId": 2,
"name": "WEB"
},
{
"activationTypeId": 3,
"name": "Channel"
}
]

<div v-show="Object.values(activationTypes).includes('Channel')"> 
<p>test<test>
</div>
```

Comment: there is no "JSON object" ... it's just an array of objects you're dealing with, correcting that thought may help you actually try to solve your own problem ... `Object.values(activationTypes)` is an array of objects, you need to check if one of those objects has a name property with the value `Channel`

Answer (score 4):

Simple Check:

```
activationTypes.some( item => item['name'] === 'Channel' );
```

Reference:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some

Comment: you beat me to it by few secs :)

Comment: @nizantz you messed with the best

Answer (score 1):

Use [`.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to search for the element by name:

```js
new Vue({
     el:"#app",
     data(){
          return{
               activationTypes: [
                    {
                    "activationTypeId": 1,
                    "name": "SMS"
                    },
                    {
                    "activationTypeId": 2,
                    "name": "WEB"
                     },
                     {
                     "activationTypeId": 3,
                     "name": "Channel"
                      }
                ]
           }
     }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
     <div v-show="activationTypes.find(e=>e.name=='Channel')"> 
          <p>test</p>
     </div>
</div>
```